# D3js Time parsing

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use D3js Time to parse this timestamp

```
11-01-2017 1:48:00 PM
```

I have typed

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your string ends with `PM`, you're missing a `%p` at the end of the specifier. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format):

> %p - either AM or PM.

Here is the demo:

```js
var date = "11-01-2017 1:48:00 PM";
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %p");

console.log(parseDate(date))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```